# Site redirecting constantly?

Tags: php, apache, loops, redirect, dns

After a LOT of server trouble we are now seeing this:

http://www.unislim.com/

What the hell is happening here!?

Looks like a local DNS issue?

Can anyone point us in the right direction as the homepage is down but everything else is fine e.g: http://www.unislim.com/slim-with-us/find-a-meeting

I have racked my brains for HOURS over this.

Comment: I don't get a redirect loop, just the home page. According to [downforeveryoneorjustme.com](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://www.unislim.com/) it's also fine from elsewhere, must be an issue local to your network

Comment: I get a redirect loop in Chrome (from the UK)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this line in the meta-tag which you should not have:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.unislim.com/">
```

This is the cause of the loop.

Comment: Thank you guys! Some IDIOT put an index.html with just that on it.

Comment: @MylesGray Don't worry, it can happen ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should remove this line from your homepage

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.unislim.com/">
```